# "Trivial" part of the Portmanteau-Theorem

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(E,\mathcal{E})$ be a topological space equipped with the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{E}$. Furthermore, let
$$
\mathcal{M}_{f}(E) := \{\text{finite measures on } (E,\mathcal{E})\}.$$
and
$$\mathcal{M}_{1}(E) := \{\mu \in \mathcal{M}_{f}(E): \mu(E) = 1\}.$$
Now we consider $\mu, \mu_{1}, \mu_{2}, \dots \in \mathcal{M}_{1}(E)$.

My question is: why is $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \mu_n(F) \leq \mu(F)$ for all measurable closed subsets $F$ equivalent to $\liminf_{n \to \infty} \mu_n(G) \geq \mu(G)$ for all measurable open subsets $G$?

Comment: Do $\mu$ and the $\mu_i$ have the same finite measure? Where did you find this version of Portmanteau?

Comment: Note that when $\mathcal{E}$ is indiscrete (as an example), the equivalence itself would imply $$\liminf \mu_n(E) \leq \mu(E) \leq \limsup \mu_n(E),$$ which is nowhere assumed.  I think that typically we would have these statements applied to the probability measures $\frac{\mu_n}{\mu_n(E)}, \frac{\mu}{\mu(E)}$ instead of directly to $\mu_n, \mu$...

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thanks for the hint. I've edited the question. Now it should be a true statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement is not true. The case $\mu_n = 0$ and $\mu$ any non-zero measure gives you a counterexample.

If you assume all $\mu_n, \mu$ have the same finite measure, then the statement is true.

Assume all measures have finite measure $M$ for example. Let $G$ be any open subset of $E$. Take $F = E-G$. It is a closed subset of $E$, and $E=F\sqcup G$. Then, since the measures are finite, $\mu_n(G) = \mu_n(E) - \mu_n(F) = M - \mu_n(F)$ and the same statement holds for $\mu$ instead of $\mu_n$.

Then $\lim \sup_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\mu_n(G) = M - \lim \inf_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\mu_n(F) \geq M - \mu(F) = M - (M - \mu(G)) = \mu(G)$.

The proof is similar for the other way of the equivalence.

Comment: or slightly stronger, if you merely assume $\mu_n(E) \to \mu(E)$, with almost the same proof.